# Does the bane magic weapon property work like greater magic weapon or weapon enhancement for DR

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

The [weapon property bane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/bane/) is a wonderful boost to a weapon on the occasions where its the right bane. One effect is that the weapon enhancement is +2 than what the weapon states, so a +1 bane (human) sword is actually a a +3 weapon against humans. But when dealing with creatures that have DR, the difference enhancement levels matter for [overcoming DR](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Damage-Reduction), and other sources like [magic weapon greater](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon/) while increasing the enhancement, do not affect DR.

from magic weapon greater

> This bonus does not allow a weapon to bypass damage reduction aside from magic.

Since the weapon property doesnt have the same wording as the spell, my thoughts are that it would be effective against higher DR types, but I have nothing to stand on for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the bane weapon property: "Against a designated foe, the weapon’s enhancement bonus is +2 better than its actual bonus."  This doesn't have any kind of qualifier or limiter like *greater magic weapon* does, specifying that it doesn't count for DR.  It simply raises the enhancement bonus by two points, therefore **bane is effective for overcoming DR with the raised enhancement bonus**.

Comment: So, lack of text, errata, and FAQ means this is valid, good to know

Comment: d20pfsrd didn't have any errata or FAQ entries shown for it, at least, which is good enough for me.  If it was less assertive in the wording - "counts as +2 better than its actual bonus for attack and damage rolls" or something, there'd be wiggle room.  But as it is, it just says **is +2 better**, so I can't read it otherwise.